Problema con BindinGContext NET MAUI
Tengo una pagina de NET MAUI (MAUI Content Page) que al abrirla se cierra la app. Si saco el bindingcontext funciona pero no muestra datos obviamente:

     public MvTareas()
     {

      ListaTareasEnCurso = new ObservableCollection<Tarea>();
      ListaTareasFinalizadas = new ObservableCollection<Tarea>();
      Tasks = new ObservableCollection<Tarea>();
      obtenerTareas(Preferences.Get("idAgente", ""));

      obtenerTareasP(Preferences.Get("idAgente", ""));
      obtenerTareasC(Preferences.Get("idAgente", ""));
      // Inicialización de UI
      ShowAsignadas();
      IsAsignadasVisible = true;
      IsEnCursoVisible = false;
      IsFinalizadasVisible = false;
      AsignadasTabColor = "Teal";
      EnCursoTabColor = "Transparent";
      FinalizadasTabColor = "Transparent";
      AsignadasTextColor = "White";
      EnCursoTextColor = "Black";
      FinalizadasTextColor = "Black";
 
     }


Ese es el constructor de mi clase que bindeo en xaml. el caso es que quiero mostrar 3 listas de tareas(aceptadas,en curso y finalizadas), para lo cual tengo 3 observableCollection que se rellenan con los 3 metodos que tengo luego. A continuacion muestro uno de ellos(en los demas cambia la lista y la url de api nada mas):
public async Task obtenerTareas(string idAgente)
{

   try
   {

       // URL de la API que proporciona la lista de tareas
       string apiUrl = "https://tasknow.cl/rest-api/AgentesRetails?agenteRetailGET=" + idAgente;
  

       // Crear una instancia de HttpClient
       HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

       // Realizar una solicitud HTTP GET a la API
       HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiUrl);

       // Si la solicitud fue exitosa
       if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
       {
           // Leer el contenido de la respuesta como una cadena JSON
           string jsonContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

           // Deserializar la cadena JSON en una lista de objetos de tipo Tarea
           ObservableCollection<Tarea> tareas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Tarea>>(jsonContent);
        
               Tasks.Clear(); // Limpia la lista existente
               foreach (var tarea in tareas)
               {
               
                   Tasks.Add(tarea);
               }

        


       }

       else
       {
           await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "Error en la respuesta de la API: " + response.StatusCode, "OK");
       }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "Excepción: ", ex.Message);

   }
}


como veran son metodos asyncronos, no se si tiene algo que ver, pero el constructorde una clase en C# no admite async por lo que no puedo usar await en la llamada a los metodos.
Entonces de que manera podria al construir el binding o entrar al xaml llamar al listado de tareas para mostrarlo?
No se que estoy haciendo mal.
Bueno agrego que ahora abre la pagina pero cuando intenta bindear la coleccion de tareas se cierra:
     public ObservableCollection<Tarea> ListaTareasAsignadas
 {
     get => _listaTareasAsignadas;
     set
     {
         if (_listaTareasAsignadas != value)
         {
             _listaTareasAsignadas = value;
             OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ListaTareasAsignadas));
         }
     }
 }
 public ObservableCollection<Tarea> Tasks
 {
     get => _tasks;
     set
     {
         if (_tasks != value)
         {
             _tasks = value;
             OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Tasks));
         }
     }
 }


 public ObservableCollection<Tarea> ListaTareasEnCurso
 {
     get => _listaTareasEnCurso;
     set
     {
         if (_listaTareasEnCurso != value)
         {
             _listaTareasEnCurso = value;
             OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ListaTareasEnCurso));
         }
     }
 }

 public ObservableCollection<Tarea> ListaTareasFinalizadas
 {
     get => _listaTareasFinalizadas;
     set
     {
         if (_listaTareasFinalizadas != value)
         {
             _listaTareasFinalizadas = value;
             OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ListaTareasFinalizadas));
         }
     }
 }

Es decir no entiendo porque si creo un objeto no me lo enlaza

Bueno.. aca tenes todo un tema.. dado que esos metodos van a tardar mas de lo que tarda el resto de las cosas, puede que el contexto este tratando de bindear cosas en null al momento de querer iniciar... Aca para mi gusto, es un error todavia de net... tenes que buscar algun workaround.. por ejemplo, un timer que ejecute esas tareas despues de iniciar el form.. o ejecutar todo en serie... eso ya queda a tu gusto...

En serie viene a ser de manera sincronica..y si pongo un timer el tiempo de espera lo pongo manualmente?

si.. si buscas estas cosas vas a ver que es algo a lo que no le encontraron solucion todavia... tal vez, podrias traer otro form de carga antes de este, que llene los objetos, y luego pase esos objetos a este... estrategias hay varias, depende de tu sistema...

el problema es solo en modo release no en modo debug, porque puede ser?

tenes puntos de interrupcion prendidos???

no.. no intente colocar puntos de interrupcion

en modo release los sistemas funcionan mucho mas rapido, y en modo debug cualquier punto de interrupcion relentiza toda la ejecucion, al punto que algunas funciones asincronicas llamadas sincronicamente funcionan bien.. pero lo que decis es raro igual.. se ve que hay milesimas de diferencia que se dan en debug...

claro tendria que primero cargar las listas de tareas y luego la pantalla

pensalo de esta forma.. capaz que tu llamada a la api tarda 1 segundo... seria logico mostrar algun tipo de control, no en el load de la pagina, si no despues, cuando ya esta desplegada, que mostrara que se esta procesando... en tu caso, yo iria por el timer y unos spinner hasta tanto este todo cargado...
